# YII2 push notification in a browser

Tags: php, push-notification, yii2

I have to implement notification to users when the news on a site is added.

I have done this via email and now I have to do this notification in a browser. I guess, **I should implement a push notification**.

How can I add a push or any other suitable notifications in a browser ?